# Why doesn't my Wiener process simulation work?

Tags: probability, simulation, stochastic-processes

The Wiener process at time $t=0$ is $0$.

It has independent increments, so  $W_t-W_0 \sim N(0,t-0)$, but wouldn't it mean that $W_t\sim N(0,t)$ for every $t$?

But if I try to simulate a a Wiener-process  in excel, it won't look like a Wiener process at all.

Comment: How do you try to simulate a Wiener process? Can you add more details about your approach (and perhaps a plot of what your outcomes look like)

Comment: @JuhoKokkala I just generate $N(0,t)$ distributed random numbers.

Comment: The *increments* are independent: plot(ts(cumsum(rnorm(10^4, 0, 0.01)), frequency = 100))

Comment: This is *so* in the Hot Network Questions list because of the name "Wiener" in the title.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@FelB you are not simulating a Wiener process because, tough $W_t \sim N(0, t)$ they are not independent one from the other (If you simulate $N(0,t)$ independents. in n cells you won't get a WP).

What are independent are the increments.

In Excel, you could simulate n i.i.d $N(0,1)$ in a column, then  compute the cumulative sum (i.e if in column A you have the simulated random variables, you set B1 = A1, and then B2 = B1 + A2, B3 = B2 + A3,...).

PLotting B is a fair approximation to a Wiener process and its quite standard.

Comment: Why aren't they independent?

Comment: Because what are independents are the increments. You could think about every $W_t$ as a sum of all the previous t-1 steps and a random increment distributed N(0,1). So if $W_{t-1}$ has a certain value, then $W_t$ won't be independent from it, as it formed by that value plus a random increment. I'm not being very formal.

Answer (score 3):

Just to expand the answer above: the key property for a Brownian motion is that $B_t - B_s \sim N(0,t-s)$ for any $t > s$, and the increments are independent for disjoint intervals.

A corollary of this is indeed that $B_t \sim N(0,t)$, but that's not much good for simulation.

Instead, take a small time step $h > 0$, say.  Simulate independent $N(0,h)$ variables, say $D_1,D_2, \ldots$ for the increments.  Then take $B_{nh} = \sum_{i=1}^n D_i$.